# $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff, and has a countable family of compact subsets covering $X$, then $X$ is second-countable

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff, and has a countable family of compact subsets whose union is all of $X$. I want to show that $X$ is second-countable.
Suppose the family of countable compact subsets are labelled $C_i$, $i \in \Bbb N$, 
Then there are a couple of ideas that come to mind but I am having trouble putting it all together.

1) Taking the complements of the $C_i$ (problem: what if an element is in all of them, also the complements might not satisfy the requirements of a basis)

2) Using local compactness to say that every point has a compact set containing it with an open neighborhood (also containing it), but how will this relate to the $C_i$ ?

Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not even true that compact Hausdorff spaces are second-countable. (Of course, a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact and can be covered by a countable family of compact subsets.)

An example is the ordinal space $[ 0 , \omega_1 ]$ (where $\omega_1$ denotes the least uncountable ordinal).

- As a linearly-ordered space, $[0 , \omega_1 ]$ is Hausdorff.
- Since $[0 , \omega_1]$ has a greatest element, it is compact (this is essentially because there are no infinite strictly decreasing sequences of ordinals).
- It is not second-countable because any base must include the singletons $\{ \alpha \}$ where $\alpha < \omega_1$ is a successor ordinal, and there are uncountably many of these.

More information about this space can be found on the following post on Dan Ma's Topology Blog:

- [The First Uncountable Ordinal](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/)

(If you want a *non-compact* example of a locally compact σ-compact Hausdorff space that is not second-countable you can just take a disjoint union of countably-infinite copies of $[0,\omega_1]$.)

Comment: So my conclusion is false?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Correct: it is not true that every locally compact, σ-compact Hausdorff space is second-countable.

Comment: +1............ $[0,\omega_1]$ is not even first-countable.

Comment: Why dooes the base have to include singletons and not larger open sets that could encompass them

Comment: @IntegrateThis Note that given a $\alpha < \omega_1$ the open interval $( \alpha , \alpha+2)$ is the singleton $\{ \alpha+1 \}$, so these singletons are open. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, for every such $\alpha+1$ there must be some $U \in \mathcal{B}$ with $\alpha+1 \in U \subseteq \{ \alpha+1 \}$, meaning $U = \{ \alpha + 1 \}$.  (More generally, call an open subset $U$ of a topological space $X$ _minimally open_ if there is no open set $V$ satisfying $\emptyset \subsetneq V \subsetneq U$. Then a base for a topological space must include all of the minimally open subsets.)

Comment: Why can't $\alpha + 1, \alpha +2$ belong to the same base element?

Comment: @IntegrateThis They can, and since open neighbourhoods of a limit ordinals $\lambda$ have a subset of the form $(\beta,\lambda]$ which itself contains infinitely many ordinals less than the limit there is a fairly good chance that $\alpha+1$ and $\alpha+2$ will both belong to some set in the base. But there _has_ to be a base element containing _only_ $\alpha+1$, and another that contains _only_ $\alpha+2$, .... Because all of these singleton sets _have_ to belong to the base I can conclude that the space is not second-countable.

Comment: @stochasticrandomness OK! I get it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following qualifies as a counterexample . . .

Let $k$ be a cardinal number with $k > c$, where $c=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Let $I=[0,1]$ with the usual topology, and let $X$ be the product of $k$ copies of $I$.

Then

- $X$ is compact and Hausdorff.$\\[4pt]$

  $X$ is locally compact.$\\[4pt]$

  $X$ is covered by itself, so $X$ qualifies as being covered by a countable union of compact sets.$\\[4pt]$

  The cardinality of the topology on $X$ is greater than $c$ (since $k > c$).$\\[4pt]$

But $X$ is not second countable.

Suppose instead that $X$ had a countable base, $B$ say.

Then since every open subset of $X$ is the union of some subset of $B$, it would follow that the cardinality of the topology on $X$ is at most the cardinality of the power set of $B$, hence at most $c$, contradiction.

Comment: Right. And $k\gt\mathfrak c$ is more than you need: if $k$ is an uncountable cardinal, then $I^k$ is not even first countable. If $k\gt\mathfrak c$ then $I^k$ is not separable.